# Conditional rendering in react prop

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, react-props, conditional-rendering

I want to ask if this possible in react while passing props or something similar. Eslint underlined the whole process in red.

```
Component A, 
enter code here
<div>
<button style={{style:props.submit}}> Submit</button>
<button style={{style:props.loading}}> Loading</button>
</div>


Component B
import ComponentA from 'A',

export default class ComponentB extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super();
this.state = {
     load:false,
    }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.setState({
    load:true,
  })
 }

 render () {
 return (
 <ComponentA  {this.state.load ? (props.loading): (props.submit)}/>
  )

 }
```

Comment: `<ComponentA  {...this.state.load ? props.loading : props.submit} />`

Comment: @Martin I don't think that would work. First if I'm correct I believe the order of operations would spread `load` before processing the ternary. Second I don't think it would be able to determine the prop names automatically.

Comment: I think you'd need to do: `<ComponentA  {...(this.state.load ? {loading: props.loading} : { submit: props.submit})} />`

Comment: <ComponentA  {...(this.state.load ? { loading: props.loading} : { submit: props.submit}) } />

Comment: Thanks everyone for these. 
While trying to implement these, the prop values needs to be assigned because they are style properties,
<ComponentA { . . . ( this.state.load ? { loading: props.loading = ' none '  } : { submit: props.submit = 'flex ' }) } /> and this is bringing out errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
const newProps = this.state.load ? {loading: props.loading} : {submit: props.submit}

<ComponentA  {...newProps} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the props needs to be assigned values and it is not looking like it is possible.i am talking about something like 

const newProps = this.state.load ? { loading : props . loading="none"} : {submit: props.submit="flex"}

Comment: What do you mean? `props . loading="none"`

Comment: props.loading is a style property. it needs a value. in Component A, i have something like this button style={{style:props.loading}}>Loading</button>